# How to change formatting of google spreadsheet columns and rows?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

How can I alter/change/set the:

- text color
- background color
- width
- text wrapping

of a specific cell range, or whole rows and columns in a google spreadsheet from NodeJs?

I'm currently using the `googleapis` npm package, but happy to use a different one.

A direct REST call is also fine - if there's an API?

Comment: Did you do any research?? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request
All of what you ask has API available. [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Answer (score -1):

Things you've mentioned can be found in [Sheets API Basic Formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting):

> The Sheets API allows you to update the formatting of cells and ranges
>   within spreadsheets. The examples on this page illustrate how some
>   common formatting operations can be achieved with the API. In
>   addition, you may find addition examples using conditional formatting
>   in the [Conditional
>   Formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting)
>   recipe page.